Resistance/Reluctance model, magnetic analog of Kirchhoff's Voltage Law, and magnetized matter
In engineering, there is a model, known as the Resistance–reluctance model that is used for solving problems in magnetics by solving analogous problems in electronic circuits. The tools used for solving these analogous electronic circuit problems are Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL), Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL) and Ohm's Law.
A version of KVL under magnetostatic conditions can be easily derived from the fact that under magnetostatic conditions, the E field is conservative. Therefore the path integral of the E field around a loop is 0. A magnetostatic version of KCL can be easily derived from the fact that under magnetostatic conditions, the divergence of the current density field J is everywhere 0.
Hopkinson's Law a/k/a Rowland's Law is a magnetic analog to Ohm's Law. It states that
$$F_m = \Phi\mathscr{R}_m$$
where $F_m$ is a magnetomotive force, $\Phi$ is magnetic flux, and $\mathscr{R}_m$ is magnetic reluctance.
The divergence of a magnetic B field is always 0. This gives us a magnetic analog to Kirchhoff's Current Law.
In general, a magnetic B field is not conservative. However, within a simply connected region of space in which there are no currents (including no Maxwell's displacement current) a B field is conservative. Thus, within such a region, B can be considered the gradient of some scalar potential field $\Psi_m$. This gives us, within that region, a magnetic analog to Kirchhoff's Voltage Law.
However, the Resistance/Reluctance Model is supposed to work, not only in vacuo, but also, (and for practical purposes, especially) with regions of space that have magnetizable matter. Magnetized matter may be thought of as matter with bound volume current density $J_b$, and bound surface current density $K_b$. In magnetostatic conditions, the bound surface current is not found in the interior of a body with uniform permeability, but only in on the surface of such a body. Further, if a body with uniform permeability also has uniform magnetization, it is said (for example in Griffiths) that there is no volume current density in the interior of the body either. These conditions allow us to conclude that the curl of B is 0 everywhere in such a region, that the B field is therefore conservative within that region, and that, assuming the region is simply connected, we may assign a scalar magnetic potential. All of the requirements for a magnetic analog of KVL apply.
This argument, however, fails to give us our desired result if the body in question is NOT uniformly magnetized.
It could be that:

When a magnetizable body is magnetized by an externally applied magnetic source, the resulting (combined) field is uniform within the body. Now this is definitely not true in the case of a toroid encircling a long conductor with current flowing through it. By symmetry arguments, the flux within the toroid is not uniform, but varies radially. But a toroid is not simply connected, so perhaps the magnetic field is uniform in simply connected bodies, but not in bodies with holes.

Or it could be that

Even though the field within a body described above is not uniformly magnetized, nevertheless, the current density field within the body satisfies some constraint such that a scalar magnetic potential can nevertheless be defined. What that constraint might be, I don't know.

Or, it could be that

A magnetized body does not in general have a uniform magnetization, and the lack thereof entails that a scalar magnetic potential does not exist in that body, and the lack of such a scalar magnetic potential entails that no magnetic analog of Kirchhoff's Voltage Law exists, but nevertheless, despite the Resistance/Reluctance Model being inexact, it is sufficiently accurate for many practical purposes.

My question is, which of the three options above, or some fourth option I haven't listed is the actual state of affairs?
